# Using fb:request-form "Something's gone wrong. We're working to get it fixed as soon as we can."

Tags: fbml, xfbml, serverfbml

I have been using `fb:request-form` for my "Friend invite form" for a while now, but all of a sudden I am having problems. It renders everything perfectly. However, when I am all done and I submit it says something went wrong and it shows me a little dialog:

> "Something's gone wrong. We're working to get it fixed as soon as we can.".

I have this in all my applications (live and test), and I am using the following code (from one of my test applications).

```
<fb:serverFbml width= "750">
    <script type="text/fbml" >
        <fb:fbml width = "750">
            <fb:request-form type="Pannemantest" type="XFBML" invite="true" method="POST" action="http://michaelp.dev.gamepoint.net/framework/mainsite/facebookfriendinvite.php?&submit=1 " content="Hi! Come and join me in PartyDice: The most exciting dicegame on Facebook. Roll the dice, mark your score and beat your opponent. Use your FREE Daily Credits to play NOW!&lt;fb:req-choice url=&quot;http://apps.facebook.com/pannemantest/&quot; label=&quot;Join the fun!&quot; &gt;">
                <fb:multi-friend-selector style='width: 650px;' actiontext="Have even more fun by inviting your friends!" showborder="true" exclude_ids="" />
            </fb:request-form>
        </fb:fbml>
    </script>
</fb:serverFbml>
```

I am not sure what caused this behavior, and I can't find anything wrong with my code (since this exact code has been online for a really long time, and nothing goes wrong with the rendering). Maybe I didn't look properly, but I couldn't find any changes announced or anything like that either for this form.

What should I do? Is there another way of producing the same form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution, from:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/288168691208443?browse=search_4e9fc696c07fd0895788720

"add import_external_friends=false to your  and it will resolve the issue."